# understanding element dimension in react native inspector on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

[image]

I am trying to figure out dimensions of a react native element on iOS simulator using the inspector of the simulator. Here i see this element with 0 margin and padding and width of 394 and height of 82.5.

But above those width and height dimension there is also another measurement (10.0, 144.5). What this dimension refers to?

**Edit:**
After some investigation it seems those numbers are distance of the element's left and top edge in respect to mobile screen considering that start at 0,0